# Application on System Startup. After CTRL ALT DEL Form is not Displaying

Tags: c#, forms, startup

My Goal (before I explain anything else) is to have an Application that:

1. An Application that runs at System Startup (before logging in at CTRL ALT DEL screen)
2. Log into Computer (CTRL ALT DEL)
3. See the Application Form (System.Windows.Forms.Form) AFTER logging in (after CTRL ALT DEL screen)

Item #3 is my trouble. I am not asking for nor need help with Items #1 & #2.

I have a standard c# .NET 4.0 Application that displays a Form when you run the Application

If I am logged in (past the CTRL ALT DEL screen) and run the Application (double click on the Exe) it works fine. Absolutely no surprises about that...

If I use the Windows Task Scheduler to run my application with a Trigger of "At system startup" here is what happens...

1. Computer Starts Up
2. Sitting at the CTRL ALT DEL screen
3. My Application has started in the background as "Admin"
4. I press CTRL ALT DEL and login as "Admin"
5. The Form is not displayed
6. I DO however see that my Application is listed in the Task Manager
7. Also, the Form.OnShown event fires. I have a Method OnShown subscribed to the Form.Shown event that creates a folder. I looked and indeed it created a folder. Proof that the event is firing. This causes me to have the following questions:

Is the Form (System.Windows.Forms.Form) working correctly?
Is it some other "behind the scenes" issue that I am unware of?
Does it matter whether a user is/isn't logged in when a Form is started/displayed/initialized?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  I'm not sure what we can do without code.  Please take a look at [How do I ask a Good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I don't think we need code for a standard winforms application. This question seems fine to me as it is.

Comment: When you see the application in the task manager, what user does it say it's running as?

Comment: When you see the application in the task manager, what session id does it have. Is it 0? (You can add Session Id column in task manager)

Answer (score 1):

If your application starts without a Desktop, the form is being created in a new session and when you log another one is created.

It's better if instead of start your app at boot, you start a service and when the session starts up then open your app with the form.

This may help you: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35773/Subverting-Vista-UAC-in-Both-32-and-64-bit-Archite